# How to scroll as long as a button is pressed in a textarea with React.js?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, scroll, scrollbar

I want to perform an action which is to scroll up and down as long as a button is pressed. To do that I did set a variable to false, and when I long press on a button it turns true, and it keep on executing a function as long as it's true, once the mouse is up the variable turns false and the function stops working. But it doesn't seem to work. So where do you think the problem lies? How can I scroll as long as a button is pressed with React.js?

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

export default function App() {

  const okay = document.getElementById("text");
  const [skate, setSkate] = useState(false);

  const goUp = (id) => {
    if (id.scrollTop !== 0) {
      id.scrollTo({
        top: id.scrollTop - 10,
        left: 0,
        behavior: "smooth"
      });
    }
  };

  const goDown = (id) => {
    id.scrollTo({
      top: id.scrollTop + 10,
      left: 0,
      behavior: "smooth"
    });
  };

  const goUpSmooth = (id) => {
    setSkate(true);
    while (skate === true) {
      id.scrollTo({
        top: id.scrollTop + 10,
        left: 0,
        behavior: "smooth"
      });
    }
  };

  const goDownSmooth = (id) => {
    setSkate(true);
    while (skate === true) {
      if (id.scrollTop !== 0) {
        id.scrollTo({
          top: id.scrollTop - 10,
          left: 0,
          behavior: "smooth"
        });
      }
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <button
        onClick={() => goUp(okay)}
        onMouseDown={() => goUpSmooth(okay)}
        onMouseUp={() => setSkate(false)}
      >
        Up
      </button>
      <br />
      <textarea id="text" placeholder="YOUR NOTES" />
      <br />
      <button
        onClick={() => goDown(okay)}
        onMouseDown={() => goDownSmooth(okay)}
        onMouseUp={() => setSkate(false)}
      >
        Down
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Because of the useState lifecycle, when the while loop is executed, the state has not been updated.

Answer (score 1):

You can call `scrollTo` once with smooth behavior and then stop it on mouseup event.

[Working example](https://codesandbox.io/s/friendly-johnson-5urfy2?file=/src/App.js)